# Is this good approach to use Innerclass In ZK and JSF for Component Variable binding?

Tags: java, jsf, inner-classes, zk

I have different projects in **ZK Architecture** and **JSF Architecture** , in my applcation i am creating inner classes for binding the data from **ZUL**(*In case of ZK*) and **Xhtml**(*in case of Jsf*).So every **ViewModel**(*In case of ZK*) and **Managedbean**(*In case of JSF*) have a inner class which is used to bind the values of components of that particular **ZUL** and **XHTML** page. Is this approach is good or i have to create a separate POJO class for Component value bindng.

Comment: Any one have any idea?

Comment: In ZK, I'd suggest separate POJO class for data. Let VM being VM, data being data. Also I remembered there're some issues of accessing inner class but forgot the actual scenario.